# Trouble with DES_ENCRYPT in AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, encryption, amazon-web-services, des, rds

I am having trouble with DES_ENCRYPT on the Amazon Web Services RDS MySQL database - the AWS RDS is SSL so it should support the DES_ENCRYPTION - in particular, WHEN I Run the SQL query from php_myadmin or the cli, with commands like  -

```
 SELECT `ID`,  DES_ENCRYPT( `Name`,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') FROM names;
```

it works, and I see a list of ids and encrypted names
But if I run

```
'UPDATE names SET `Name` = DES_ENCRYPT( `Name`,'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

the query looks like it works, but the `Name` column just contains blanks - Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: What do you perceive to be the purpose behind doing this?  What is the data type of your `Name` column?

Comment: It is a person's name  - the database has been in trial, and now has to have sensitive material encrypted before production

Comment: What do you mean by it "*has to have sensitive material encrypted before production*"?  What is the threat model?  Given that you transmit both the plaintext and the key to the RDBMS, you're only defending against attacks at a lower level than that (e.g. at the storage layer); where the RDBMS is provided by the same party as the storage layer, I struggle to see any significant security advantage here.  Also, I was asking with which [data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/data-types.html) you have created your `Name` column?

Comment: This is medical information, and the data has to be encrypted at rest to meet HIPAA requirements-  the name is varchar(255)

Comment: As stated in Amazon's document [Creating Healthcare Data Applications 
to Promote HIPAA and HITECH Compliance](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_HIPAA_Whitepaper_Final.pdf): "*When sending data to Amazon S3 for either short term or long term storage, we highly recommend encrypting data 
before transmission. We also recommend against putting any PHI or other sensitive data, including keys, in Amazon S3 
metadata.*"

Comment: AWS support helped with the answer - I had not activated SSL on my RDS dbinstance - no PHI is stored in S3, only in the RDS, and there it will be encrypted at rest and in transit   - Thanks for your help, best

Comment: Also the DES Encrypt function only worked on latin1_general_ci collation - not UTF8